# Setting SKVideoNode.isPaused = false immediately starts playing the video

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm having a hard time understanding how to use `SKVideoNode` properly. I'm making a simple game where the player has to complete against the "computer" whose moves are rendered in form of a pre-recorded video.

When the game begins the video should be paused, so I call `pause()` on it. Once the human player begins his/her moves the artificial player's video starts playing. This part is working fine.

Once the time is up, the game scene is paused via setting `isPaused = true` on my `SKScene` subclass (let's call it `GameScene`).

However, the player also has a chance to restart the game via pressing a button. When the game is restarted, the game scene is "unpaused" and the game state is reset like this:

```
gameView.isPaused = false // gameView is an SKView presenting the scene
gameScene.resetGameState()
```

The `resetGameState` method will simply reset players' scores and pause and rewind the video:

```
public func resetGameState() {
    isGameStarted = false
    isGameStopped = false

    artificialPlayerScoreboard.score = 0
    humanPlayerScoreboard.score = 0

    video.pause()
    videoPlayer.seek(to: CMTime(seconds: 0, preferredTimescale: 1))
}
```

Here is how I create the video and video player:

```
    if let videoPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "video", ofType: "mp4") {
        videoPlayer = AVPlayer(url: URL(fileURLWithPath: videoPath))
        video = SKVideoNode(avPlayer: videoPlayer)
        video.size = playerScreenSize
        video.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
        video.position = CGPoint.zero
        video.pause()
        artificialPlayerScreen.addChild(video)
    }
```

The problem is that the video starts playing immediately after the game is restarted despite being paused. I've been trying to figure out why and came up with this hack:

```
    gameView.isPaused = false

    // Can't do this immediately because the video will start plyaing.
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: DispatchTime.now() + 0.1, execute: {
        self.gameScene.resetGameState()
    })
```

Basically it does the same thing but pauses the video after a small delay.

Is this normal behaviour of `SKVideoNode`? Am I using it right?

Comment: There is a bug with Apple that I have reported numerous times, They claim it is correct behavior.  What happens if you change the pause state for a parent, the pause variable for all children changes as well, which goes against what you have programmed.  To combat this, you need to either override the pause variable for all classes, or just repause what you need paused after you unpause your view